# Laravel installing Algolia package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, traits, algolia

I am trying to install the Algolia laravel package but I am getting this error:

Trait 'App\AlgoliaEloquentTrait' not found

I follow the instructions under install, configuration and quickstart from this link:

https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel#configuration

I simply added use AlgoliaEloquentTrait; to one of my models. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Give us some code to deal with, maybe the model file :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

`use AlgoliaSearch\Laravel\AlgoliaEloquentTrait;`

at the beginning of your model.

Comment: For me was `use \AlgoliaSearch\Laravel\AlgoliaEloquentTrait;`